# Android studio 3.0 installation error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to install android studio 3.0 but I am getting the below error.I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Android studio 3.0

Java JDK:1.8

> Unable to create temporary folder: Unable to create temporary file

Answer (score 1):

Try to run setup file as **Administrator**. maybe there isn't permission to do that.